# libpng not found on pkg-config search path

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

When building cairo 1.2.6 from source I get the following error:

```
checking for cairo's PNG backend... 
configure: WARNING: Could not find libpng in the pkg-config search path
checking whether cairo's PNG backend could be enabled... no
configure: error: requested PNG backend could not be enabled
```

However I have just built libpng with the following:

```
wget ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/png/src/libpng16/libpng-1.6.7.tar.gz
tar -xzf libpng-1.6.7.tar.gz
cd libpng-1.6.7
configure --prefix=/users/$USER
make 
make install
```

pkg-config looks like it can find libpng:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion libpng
1.6.7
```

Command I was running for cairo build/install:

```
wget http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.2.6.tar.gz
tar -xzf cairo-1.2.6.tar.gz
cd cairo-1.2.6
configure --prefix=/users/$USER
```

Running as a user (not root/no sudo) on RHEL5, all commands ran from tcsh terminal.